# etale fundamental group of global quotient algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I am reading about fundamental group of algebraic stacks, and in my opinion, the class of quotient stacks is an important one in algebraic stacks. However, I am not clear about how to compute fundamental groups of global quotient algebraic stacks, though I know it is very hard and case dependent.

To give some concrete examples of my questions, denote the global quotient stack by $\mathcal{X}=[Y/G]$, where $Y$ is a scheme and $G$ a smooth connected algebraic group, both defined over a field $k$. If $Y$ is simply connected, then Noohi's paper "fundamental group of algebraic stacks" says that $[Y/G]$ has trivial fundamental group. The next simplest case maybe the classifying stack of a non-simply-connected scheme, for example when $Y$ is $\mathbb{G}_m$ and $G$ acts on $Y$ trivially and $G$ is a infinite algebraic group. What I know is that the map $f:[Y/G]\to Y$ is a grebe-like morphism but unfortunately not representable. Since gerbe-like morphisms are smooth universal homeomorphisms, $f$ induces a surjection on the fundamental groups:$\pi_1([Y/G])\to \pi_1(Y)$. By Rydh's paper "Submersions and effective descent of étale morphisms", non-representable morphism of stacks typically is not of effective descent, so the kernel is in general nontrivial. However, I don't know what the kernel is or a way to control the kernel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we not prove that the sequence $\pi_1(G) -> \pi_1(Y) \to \pi_1([Y/G]) -> 1$  is exact exact using that $Y\to Y/G$ is a G-torsor?

Comment: Since $Y\to [Y/G]\to Y$ is the identity map,  $\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1([Y/G])\to \pi_1(Y)$ is also the identity. This means $\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1([Y/G])$ is injective. So if there is an exact sequence of their fundamental groups as described, then $\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1([Y/G])$ is an isomorphism, which I don't think holds in general.

Comment: Why is there such a morphism $[Y/G]\to Y$? Are you assuming this? Isn't that equivalent to saying that the $G$-torsor $Y\to [Y/G]$ is trivial (i.e., has a section)? In that case, I would say that $Y \cong [Y/G] \times G$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since $G$ acts trivially on $Y$, there is a morphism $[Y/G]\to Y$. This does not mean every torsor over a general $k$-scheme is trivial, for example, there is a map $[Y/\mathbb{G}_m]=B\mathbb{G}_m\to Y$. On the $F$-points where $F$ is a field, this is $(F\leftarrow \mathbb{G}_m\to Y)\to (F\to Y)$, since every line bundle over a field is trivial.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit rusty with stacks it seems. But isn't $B(G_Y) = BG \times_k Y$? So, you are looking at $\pi_1(BG \times_k Y)$, no?  How far is this from being $\pi_1(BG)\times \pi_1(Y)$?   In fact, what is $\pi_1(BG)$?

Comment: I think you are right, $\pi_1(BG_Y)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y)$. Thank you for your help.